# how to get data weekly wise in mysql for each month

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(es.scheduled_datetime, '%X-%V') AS date,
    COUNT(es.event_schedule_id) AS total,
    0 as type
    FROM  event_schedule es ,event_schedule_mapping esm,events e
    WHERE 
    es.event_schedule_id  = esm.event_schedule_id and
    esm.event_id = e.event_id and
    es.event_status_id in(1,2) and
    es.scheduled_datetime BETWEEN 
    '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
    GROUP BY date
    ORDER BY date
```

this is my Query using this Query i am able to display record whose count is greater than zero and below output come like this

for January month

```
'2017-01', '2', '0'
'2017-02', '2', '0'
'2017-03', '10', '0'
'2017-04', '2', '0'
'2017-05', '9', '0'
```

But  its not displaying if count is zero in second week   while i have to
 display that also :

```
'2017-01', '2', '0'
'2017-02', '0', '0'
'2017-03', '10', '0'
'2017-04', '2', '0'
'2017-05', '9', '0'
```

please suggest me how to display Record if count is zero it should week wise please suggest me

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: whats your expected output

Comment: you will need to create a subquery which generates the weeks of the month you are filtering for, and use it with an outer join on you `event_schedule` table.

Comment: expected output if count is zero then also it should show record currently showing  only those record whose count greater than zero

Comment: @MakleeLee any of your where condition might be excluding the records with 0..It would be better if your data sample is shown

Comment: how to include count  in table there are record and date is there  i am just checking record and count  but how i will display if no Record between given date

Comment: You have to check whether the conditions in your where is applicable for the records with count 0

Comment: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(es.scheduled_datetime, '%X-%V') AS date   FROM  event_schedule es 
  WHERE 
  total in(0),
   es.scheduled_datetime BETWEEN 
    '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31' 
    GROUP BY date
    ORDER BY date

Comment: Could you attach the screenshot of your data

Comment: Ok wait i will attache

Comment: http://pasteboard.co/wcabFMjTk.png check this

Comment: @affaz did u get what i am trying to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135246/discussion-between-affaz-and-maklee-lee).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get data weekly in each month from database , I have query for that try this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) as week,tbl_data.date AS date, SUM(count.calories) AS sum,tbl_data.offset AS offset from tbl_data INNER JOIN count ON count.id = tbl_data.item_id where tbl_data.user_id="+user_id+" and tbl_data.date and  MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) GROUP BY week
```